# h5py: Speed up concatenation of HDF5 datasets

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have a number of `HDF5` files that each contain large datasets of equal shapes. I would like to write all these datasets into a single file, with an additional dimension as the index of the respective dataset. The following code does exactly what I want:

```
with h5py.File("merged.mat", "w") as output_file:
    new_data = output_file.create_dataset("data", shape + (len(input_files),), dtype=dtype)
    for index, file in enumerate(input_files):
        with h5py.File(file, "r") as m_file:
            defocus_data[:,:,:,:,index] = m_file['data']
            output_file.flush()
```

The step `defocus_data[:,:,:,:,index] = m_file['data']`, however, takes a long time (minutes for an `input_file` of size ~1GB). Is there any way, I can speed this process up? I know there are low-level functions such as `h5.h5o.copy`, but don't know how to apply them here.